# How can I remove an entry from the list of installed software?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I manually deleted an application, and now I want to remove the entry in the settings list (Apps & features).

As expected, I am getting a 'Windows cannot find the uninstaller'-error when I click `Uninstall`, but unfortunately I also do not get a question asking me to remove the entry from list.

I looked in the registry at `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, but I do not see a corresponding entry either.

[image]

Comment: Try checking in HKLM `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\.` It might also be under these `{F108BACE-2CE0-447B-A953-68E2019F7B66}` .

Comment: @Dumdum good suggestion, I did find many entries there as well, but not the one I was looking for (cleaned some others, though)

Comment: What kind or program are you looking for was it installed from the MS store cause then I don't think it appears there.

Comment: I am testing our own installer generated with install4j.

Comment: apps like revouninstaller may be able to remove it for you.